# connection to database in C#

Tags: c#

i am able to connect but my connection is not working. i am making a window base app , which delete the data from table in database and return a value. connection is done, but its not deleting any data or returning the value. MY code is:

For example

Connectionname DAC;  :: Create connection

DAC = new Connectioinname(); :: intialize

DAC.Flag_Emp( argText, argDistricts, OptionBit); // Call a procedure from data base.

::  EROOR   Error   Non-invocable member 'Flag_Aesop_User.ProductionDataSet.Flag_Employee' cannot be used like a method

Comment: Dear Navi, that's nice to know. I need to pay my taxes and wash my car.

Comment: hold on guys, i am new to this site. i am trying to give information out as much i can.

Comment: This code is working , but not activity in database.

Comment: Forgot to mention , its a window base application not web.

Comment: You need to follow a tutorial to do this. just check my provided links. both are help full to simply teach you two needed concept.

Comment: Matt Ball and Sorax , thanks for helping . sometime it takes time to get use to new things and i am new here. hope one day i will be at your level , but i won't be making fun of new comers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that thing called google? What have you done so far? This is pretty generic and common task. There are tons and tons of information on how to use either Linq2Sql, Ado.net or EF to manipulate your data. If you just need to connect, than start here:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

Comment: i am able to connect but my connection is not working. i am making a window base app , which delete the data from table in database and return a value. connection is done, but its not deleting any data or returning the value. MY code is: For example::::::::::::::::::::::// Connectionname DAC;  :::::::::: Create connection:::::// DAC = new Connectioinname();:::: intialize ::::////DAC.Flag_Emp( argText, argDistricts, OptionBit); // Call a procedure from data base. ::::::::  EROOR   Error Non-invocable member 'Flag_Aesop_User.ProductionDataSet.Flag_Employee' cannot be used like a method

Answer (score 0):

These would help :

[How to: Create Connections to SQL Server Databases Using C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

[Connecting to a SQL Server Database Using C#](http://sharpertutorials.com/connecting-to-a-sql-server-database/)